# How to open a file directory when only know part of the file name

Tags: vba, excel

Ok so I am trying to quickly open a file path using 2 cell values, everything works fine if I know the information verbatim.  My issue is on the last value I will only have the first part of the file name, I have tried using the wildcard * but can't seem to get it to work.  Keep getting "Path not found error".  The second value is a project name, however, the folders also contain a description of the project.  For example I know the project name is TB1756_2156 but the folder is named "TB1756_2156 Project Description Person in Charge January 2014" this is the code I have so far:

```
     Sub Button2_Click()
     ChDrive "S:\"
     ChDir "S:\CLIENTS " & Range("B10").Value & "\Client1\" & Range("B11").Value & "*\Sample"
     strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
     End Sub
```

EDIT:
Ok so if I where to manually open the file I want to examine this would be my path: S:\CLIENTS YEAR\FOLDER NAME\Project # Description Project Lead Year\Sample\File I want.xls 
The vba I want open the dialog box and goes to the S:\CLIENTS then adds value from cell B10 then continues to FOLDER NAME\ then grabs just the Project # from cell B11 as this is all you would have handy , then would fill in the missing information, then continue to \Sample where the user would then select the file they want to open.

So manipulating the code provide by @dcromley this is what I got:

```
    Sub UseFileDialogOpen()
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .InitialFileName = "S:\CLIENTS " & Range("C10").Value & "\FOLDER NAME\ & Range("C11").Value
    .Show
    End With
    End Sub
```

My issue with this is that it only enters the Project # into the File Name: but does not actually open it.  So looking for a way to parse the directory as I have it already from my original code minus the "*\Sample" and that it would open the only folder that starts with the Project #

Comment: Another shot -- I added EDIT2 to my answer.  I am a senior citizen and am having trouble analyzing this.  Maybe we'll get shot by the SO police for continuing this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `first part of the file name` and want the filename, this will do it.
If you want a directoryname, change vbNormal to vbDirectory.

```
Sub Main()
  MsgBox FindFilename("abc", "Z:\untitled\")
End Sub

Function FindFilename$(FirstPart$, DirWhere$)
  Dim sw1&, Filename$
  Do
    If sw1 = 0 Then
      sw1 = 1
      Filename = Dir$(DirWhere, vbNormal)
    Else
      Filename = Dir$()
    End If
    If Filename = "" Then Exit Do
    If FirstPart = Left$(Filename, Len(FirstPart)) Then
      FindFilename = Filename
      Exit Function
    End If
  Loop
  MsgBox "Error - Filename not found"
End Function
```

EDIT:
From the Excel 2003 help (you have the complete (initial) dirname now, right?):

```
Sub UseFileDialogOpen()
  Dim lngCount&
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .InitialFileName = "Z:\untitled\"
    .Show
    For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
      MsgBox .SelectedItems(lngCount)
    Next lngCount
  End With
End Sub
```

EDIT2: To open a *.xls file:

```
Sub Openxls()
  Dim filename$
  filename = "z:\untitled\dave1.xls"
  Workbooks.Open filename
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you I have tested the code for the vbDirectory and it does a great job of telling me the full name.  However, thats not exactly what I want.  Im using my code to use an Open Dialog to select a directory path and then the user would select a file from the path instructed by the cell values.  I love though that you have been able to print the full name of the directory name, but I need to actually open that path, any clues?

Comment: @user258122 - I added code from the Excel help that should do it.

Comment: I appreciate the help but still not exactly what I am looking for, maybe Im not explaining myself very well I will try further.
Ok so if I where to manually open the file I want to examine this would be my path:

Comment: I appreciate the help but still not exactly what I am looking for, maybe Im not explaining myself very well I will try further.  I will add to my question as there is not enough room in the comments to explain.

Answer (score 0):

I think dcromley's approach is sound but let us simplify things a little bit.

```
Dim prjDir As String, prjName As String
Dim initialFile As String, myDirString As String

'~~> B11 contains part of the foldername
'~~> B10 value as is 
prjDir = "C:\CLIENTS\" & Range("B10") & "\Client1\" & Range("B11") & "*"
prjDir = Dir(prjDir, vbDirectory) '~~> use Dir to get the actual folder name

prjName = "C:\CLIENTS\" & Range("B10") & "\Client1\" & prjDir & "\*SAMPLE*.xls" 
prjName = Dir(prjName, vbNormal) 'use Dir to get the actual filename

initialFile = "C:\CLIENTS\" & Range("B10") & "\Client1\" & prjDir & "\" & prjName

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls"
    .FilterIndex = 1
    .InitialFileName = initialFile
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = False Then MsgBox "Please select Excel file.", vbExclamation: Exit Sub
    myDirString = .SelectedItems(1)
    .Filters.Clear
End With

Workbooks.Open myDirString '~~> Open the file
```

Is this close to what you want to achieve?
Btw, I assumed your *Project #* is unique.